# If the lights we receive from old galaxies are old, could we see ours if we were in those galaxies?

Tags: earth, speed-of-light, ftl, outer-planets

I am bit of an amateur in space and astronomy. As far as I understand the light that we receive from those galaxies is old, millions and billions of years old.

A galaxy that is 100 million light years away means that the light is that old, correct?

My question is: if one day we (humans) are able to travel faster than the speed of light (by blackhole or any other way) could we see the old Earth?

Can we see old lights or even old events on the Earth, because the light that arrives from Earth to another galaxy is millions or thousand years old?

Comment: There are several different useful ways to define distance at cosmological scales. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distance_measure It's a little complicated because of the accelerating expansion of the universe.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a better suit for https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/

Comment: We could migrate to astronomy instead. Why close specifically?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. ***IF*** you were to travel faster than light, you would be able to witness your own departure after your arrival, among many other things.

Comment: If you had a big enough telescope to see it with.

Answer (score 0):

An observer very far away from our Sun may the see the old light from our Sun too if he uses a suitable telescope. But if the observer is farther away (in lightyears) than the Sun is old, he could not see light from the Sun.

Old Events on the Earth may not be seen from such a distance, the resolution of a telescope is limited by its diameter. It would require a gigantic telescope with a huge diameter.